# How to access meta information of a job inside Spark application

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I'd like to get notified when a Cloud Dataproc job finished. Unfortunately Cloud Dataproc does not seem to provide hooks or some ways to notify a job's lifecycle, I want to implement the mechanism in my own.

I'm planning to push to Pub/Sub when a job finished from my Spark application. But how do I know an information to identify the job inside a Spark application? If I could get [User Labels](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/labels) of the job from the application underneath, I'm utilizing it by giving a unique label on submit, then include the label key and value in the Pub/Sub message.

Comment: If you're already computing a job id or user label before job submission, would it make sense to pass that in as an argument to your driver (via the args parameter on Dataproc's SparkJob: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.jobs#SparkJob)? If using gcloud, arguments are specified as: gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster ... -- arg0 arg1 ... argN

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It just works!